# Nuget can't add reference

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

after i move project and use Nuget Restore, all my project reference are broken

[image: Warning]

and in property panel:

[image: Empty]

I tried remove package folder, restore.

Reinstall but nothing work.

Comment: Did you enable package-restore in the solution?

Comment: Could it be that you used a mix of adding packages on your *solution* through Visual Studio's package manager and on some of your projects, either through PM or PM console?

Comment: @DiegoMartelli: yes, i enable package-restore, checked dlls are downloaded.

Comment: @DavidBrabant: i don't understand your question.

Comment: Let's rephrase it: how did you add your packages? By right clicking at your solution level and using the package manager? By right clicking on your project(s) level and using the package manager? By using the package manger console and doing "install-package"? Or a mix of all of that?

Comment: @DavidBrabant I used console command "install-package"

Comment: Choose path to *.dll files in *.csproj file. Relative path could be broken after project move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this happened to me too, my solution, and I know it's ugly, it's to remove all nuget reference and then re-add. It's not beautiful, it's not elegant, but works quick. I wonder If someone could give us a better cleaner way.